# Sliding Drop Down Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, jquery-animate, slidedown

I have a drop down menu that I want to slide down when the Menu button is clicked and slide up when it's clicked again. Also slide up when clicking anywhere else in the document.

This is what I got so far: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zte5eh8a/2/)

HTML:

```
<nav>
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" title="Menu">Menu</a>
  <ul class="dropdown">
    <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Search</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Jquery:

```
$(function() {
  // Dropdown toggle
  $('.dropdown-toggle').click(function() {
    $(this).next('.dropdown').toggle(function() {
      $('.dropdown').stop().animate({
        top: '100%'
      }, 'slow');
    });
  });

  $(document).click(function(e) {
    var target = e.target;
    if (!$(target).is('.dropdown-toggle') && !$(target).parents().is('.dropdown-toggle')) {
      $('.dropdown').toggle(function() {
      $('.dropdown').stop().animate({
        top: '-100px'
      }, 'slow');
    });
    }
  });
});
```

The problem with what I did is the animation happens only once and only when clicking to open the drop down menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question for anyone who's interested, this is the code:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.dropdown').hide();
  $('.dropdown-toggle').click(function(e) {
    $('.dropdown').slideToggle(400);
    $('.dropdown-toggle').slideDown('active');
    $('.dropdown').toggleClass('is-active');
    return false;
  });
  $(document).click(function() {
    if ($('.dropdown').is(':visible')) {
      $('.dropdown', this).slideUp();
      $('.dropdown').removeClass('is-active');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 2em;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}
nav {
  position: relative;
}
.dropdown-toggle {
  padding: .5em 1em;
  background: #777;
  border-radius: .2em .2em 0 0;
}
.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: .5em;
  background: #777;
  min-width: 12em;
  padding: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-60px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-60px);
  transform: translateY(-60px);
  transition: transform .3s
}
.dropdown.is-active {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(30px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(30px);
  transform: translateY(30px);
  display: block
}
ul.dropdown li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul.dropdown a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: .5em 1em;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav><a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" title="Menu">Menu</a>
  <ul class="dropdown">
    <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Settings</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Search</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I used `toggleClass` and `removeClass` to add the animation I wanted and that's translate (the idea originally from [Slide and Push Menu tutorial](http://callmenick.com/post/slide-and-push-menus-with-css3-transitions)):

```
 -webkit-transform: translateY(-60px);
 -ms-transform: translateY(-60px);
 transform: translateY(-60px);
 transition: transform .3s
```

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if you are aware but there are **[`.slideUp()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideup/)**, **[`.slideDown()`](http://api.jquery.com/slidedown/)** and **[`.slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/)** methods available in jQuery to do this sliding animation up and down business.

Below is the snippet for your reference:

```js
var dropdownToggle = $('.dropdown-toggle');
var dropdown = dropdownToggle.next('.dropdown');
$(function() {
  dropdown.slideUp(0);
  $(document).on('click', function(e) {
    var target = e.target;
    if (!$(target).is('.dropdown-toggle') && !$(target).parents().is('.dropdown-toggle')) {
      if (dropdown.is(':visible')) {
        dropdown.stop(true).slideUp();
      }
    }
  });
  dropdownToggle.on('click', function() {
    dropdown.stop(true).slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
body { padding: 2em; }
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}
nav { position: relative; }
.dropdown-toggle {
  padding: .5em 1em;
  background: #777;
  border-radius: .2em .2em 0 0;
}
ul.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  margin-top: .5em;
  background: #777;
  min-width: 12em;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 .2em .2em;
}
ul.dropdown li { list-style-type: none; }
ul.dropdown a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: .5em 1em;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav><a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" title="Menu">Menu</a>
  <ul class="dropdown">
    <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Search</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**Notes:**

- You had CSS `transition` applied on the same element and you were also trying to apply animation via the use of `.animate()` method of jQuery on the same element. Both were conflicting each other. I have removed the CSS `transition` parts.
- I also have removed the `height: 0` part and you will notice that there is a `dropdown.slideUp(0)` line up there which basically applies a `.slideUp()` animation of `0` duration to immediately set `height: 0` on the element.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I didn't want to use `.slideUp` because the text doesn't really slide down. As you can see here: [link](http://sorayabakhtiar.com/) the tabs text also slides down.

Comment: so you don't want the slide down effect and you want them to simply fade in? your attempts showed me otherwise.

Comment: Did you get a chance to see the example in the link? [Example](http://sorayabakhtiar.com/). I do want it to slide down, but with `SlideUp` the text doesn't slide down from behind the menu button.

Comment: In that example, am I supposed to scroll a little down so I can see `Menu` button in action. Once I click on that button, the `outfits`, `shopping` etc options do slide down. but they are behind the whole header-with-the-logo bar. I am sorry I am finding it hard to understand what exactly you are after.